# list of objects in my recycler view maxing out at 20

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

I'm using an `ArrayList` to gather all the text from the objects in my recycler view like this

```
    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < SpeakRecyclerGrid.recyclerView.getChildCount(); i++) {
      list.add(
        ((EditText)SpeakRecyclerGrid.recyclerView.getChildAt(i)).getText().toString());
    }
```

if i call System.out.println(list.size()); it will print the right amount but only till it maxes out, which seems to be really early. On my phone it will only go up to 20 on my tablet it will get up to about 24 and the amount of characters in list can get up to 300 quite easily i've been reading into it and it doesn't seem like it should be happening and using an array instead doesn't look like it will work but i cant find a good way to get around it, any ideas?

Comment: i think getChildCount returns only visible item count

Comment: thats  interesting ill check this out thank you

Comment: @USKMobility please add you comment as the answer i changed my call to grab the info from my list rather than my recycler and it works perfectly this is my new code                                                                                                     for (int i = 0; i < SpeakRecyclerGrid.cardMakerList.size(); i++) {
                  list.add(SpeakRecyclerGrid.cardMakerList.get(i).getSpeechText());
          }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getChildCount returns only visible list items. So you can not get all list items.